# jQuery sortable - item sometimes disappears on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have more than 30 sortable lists, in which a number of lists are on the left side and the other are in an accordion (see picture below - only 6 pictured). I want to be able to move items from the list in the accordion to the other lists and vice versa, but not between accordion tabs.

It works great, but there's only one annoying behaviour. Sometimes, when I try to move an item from one list to another, it will just disappear (it "flies" to the top of the screen) and end up in another list; for example: from list D to list A, but end up in accordion tab 3, or from list C to list B, but end up in accordion tab 2.

```
//for each list in the accordion, I created the sortable like this
$accordionSortableList.sortable({
    connectWith: ["#listA,#listB,#listC"],
    start: cloneContentItem,
    stop: onSortableStop,
    receive: onSortableReceive,
    revert: 100
}).disableSelection();

//for the other
$boxSortableList.sortable({
    connectWith: ["#listA,#listB,#listC,#listD,#listE,#listF"],
    receive: onSymbolChanged,
    remove: onSymbolChanged,
    revert: 100
}).disableSelection();
```

It seems to me like a wrong event is being thrown. If the dropping is successful, a `receive` event will be thrown, otherwise a `remove` event.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/frezzz_54/zpho0tw0/) is a JSFiddle link. If you drag an item from the accordion and put it e.g. a little bit on top of "box-left-1", the item will disappear and land somewhere in the accordion. I have a solution to remove the item from the accordion, but I want to have the item in the destination box as well. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: Is your website publicly available somewhere? It would be helpful to have that at least so we can try to narrow down a MCVE.

Comment: Yes I know, but unfortunately not. I will update my question with a JSFiddle if I could reproduce it.

Comment: @WilliamKunkel I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code, I defined the accordion "content panel" as a sortable, and that's where the strange behavior comes from. I have to create a sortable container and put it in the accordion.

```
$.each(rightBoxes, function(index, box) {
    var $accHeader = $("<div>").html(box.title);
    $accHeader.appendTo($("#rightPanel"));

    var $accContent = $("<div>").attr("id", box.id);

    var $contentBox = $("<div>"); // This is important
    $.each(box.items, function (idx, item) {
        var $div = $("<div>").html(item.title);
        $div.appendTo($contentBox);
    });
    $contentBox.sortable({
        connectWith: ["#left-1,#left-2,#left-3"]
    }).disableSelection();
    $contentBox.appendTo($accContent);

    $accContent.appendTo($("#rightPanel"));
});
```